# How do I generate different HTML for the last uploaded file using PHP?

Tags: php, fancybox

I am creating an image gallery in fancybox but am trying to automate image uploading.

Fancybox galleries are a collection of `<a>` tags, but the first `<a>` tag listed also has an `<img>` tag to provide a thumbnail to open like so:

```
<a href="image1.jpg"><img src="image1thumb.jpg"></a>
<a href="image2.jpg"></a>
<a href="image3.jpg"></a>
```

Currently I would have to manually add `<a>` tags for every new image I upload which would be tedious.  I would rather add the links to a mySQL database which will then be picked up by a piece of PHP.

In plain English the code would read as follows :

For the last uploaded file, show `<a href.......><img src=.......></a>` and then for all other images show `<a href........></a>` only.

I already have the code for the last uploaded file which displays as $lastupload, but am struggling with a foreach loop.  So far I have:

```
foreach ($lastupload) {
echo '<a class="fancybox" rel="'.$r["rel"].'" href="'.$r["imagelink"].'" title="'.$r["comment"].'"><img src="thumb.jpg"></a>';
        }
else {
echo '<a class="fancybox" rel="'.$r["rel"].'" href="'.$r["imagelink"].'" title="'.$r["comment"].'"></a>
      }
```

Now, I know that this code is basically useless.  I know that I need more in the initial foreach brackets, and that else shouldn't be a part of this loop (it should be foreach/ifelse), but I don't know how to proceed further.  All of the examples I've looked introduce counts which I'm not sure fits into what I'm trying to do.  Plus, no example I've looked at so far shows how to generate a list of links from a mySQL database.

Any help you can give will go a long way.

Thanks

Comment: What is that else even connected to? And your brace is still in the String literal, you never closed it.

Comment: Youre missing the point.  That code is terrible and not correct at all.  Im just trying to describe what I want and show how I don't know how to get at it.  That closing brace was a typo btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was not to look for the last uploaded file, just treat the first result of the query differently.

Here is the full code for what I got:

```
<?php
  $foo_query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $is_first=false;
  while($r=$foo_query->fetch()) {
    if($is_first) {
      echo '<a...blah blah blah><img src="thumb.jpg"></a>';
    } else {
      echo '<a...more blah></a>';
    }
  } 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at how the `foreach()` loop actually works? You don't need a count for this particular loop. Or you could loop until the end of your results (see below).

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

As for extracting links from your database, look at `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`. There are some examples of `while()` loops to run through your query.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Look at the above examples in the PHP.net manual, this is a really good source of information.

Comment: I tried to go through that page but I can't really understand it.  I'm quite happy to admit that I am far out of my depth with this, but I am in need of something and there isn't an alternative other than manually typing a load of code which I don't really want to do - so I'm trying to figure it out and not doing a great job.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question. I don't know what $r is in your example, but from what I can tell you want to do something like this:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($r as $row) {
  if ($i == 0) {
    echo '<a class="fancybox" rel="'.$row["rel"].'" href="'.$row["imagelink"].'" title="'.$row["comment"].'"><img src="'.$lastupload.'"></a>';
  }
  else {
    echo '<a class="fancybox" rel="'.$row["rel"].'" href="'.$row["imagelink"].'" title="'.$row["comment"].'"></a>
  }
  $i++;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, there were a couple of typos above that I really should have checked.  The start of the code is while($r=mysql_fetch_assoc($visuals_query))  My question is that I need to figure out how to only show img src tag for the first result of the query only.  I can make img src show for all results, but not the first

Comment: Does my solution not do this? My code starts an iterator at 0. It says, if the iterator is 0 (which is only true for the first iteration) display the <img /> tag, otherwise do not show the img tag. It then iterates at the end of each iteration of the foreach loop, meaning every iteration past the first will not show the img tag. Let me know if I'm missing something :)

Comment: No it brought up a syntax error for the line 'foreach ($lastupload)', I assume becuase it likes to see more than just $lastupload?  I also added a semi colon after $i++ as it didnt like that either

Comment: Oh yeah, you need to say $x as $y in a foreach, where $x is the array you are iterating through and $y is a temporary reference to the element you are currently working with. Please see my edit and let me know if this works.

Comment: May I ask what the $lastupload variable contains? I am starting to think you want to do `foreach($r as $row)` and then change all your $r["something"] to $row["something]

Comment: Yes - $lastupload scans a directory and grabs the filename of the last file to be added to that directory.  It's so the thumbnail for the gallery is obviously the last image to be added to the gallery.  Bear in mind that $r is used throughout the website, and not just with this gallery but with other tables and fields too

Comment: So if I understand correctly, $lastupload is this path of the image that you want to show in the first row? And $r is the result of a query? If this is true, my most recent edit should be what you are looking for.

Comment: Nope, this isnt working still.  It shows a thumbnail of the last uploaded file, but the fields are all showing random letters and characters.  It's also broken the fancybox script.  Though, this is making more sense to me - I had to put $i=0 outside of my 'while' loop as this still brought up single thumbnails for all images (and still broke fancybox).  See what there is so far at www.tomrankinmusic.com/pictest.php